# SQL OR functioning like AND

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the relevant line of code:

```
$woquery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE statusID <> 15 OR statusID <> 12 ORDER BY dateIn ASC");
```

The problem I am having is that with this code, the OR function seems to be working like an AND function.

If I change it to (for example):

```
statusID <> 15 OR statusID <> 15
```

Then it correctly excludes records with 15 for statusID, same if I set it to 12

If I have just a single WHERE function with no OR, then it also filters correctly. However, when I have both, it filters neither 12 or 15.

Comment: Your condition does not make sense, it will always be `true`, imagine all animals that are not a cat or not a dog...

Comment: @jeroen Ah yes, I see that now. Brainfart I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE **NOT IN**  for those two or operations

```
$woquery = $dbc->prepare("SELECT * FROM workorder WHERE statusID NOT IN( 15, 12) ORDER BY dateIn ASC"
```

Comment: Yep, working fine now, many thanks for your help. Will accept as soon as.